# navigation bar button not showing in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

We are using xcode 8.0 . We are facing problem for custom navigation bar button item. Custom bar button not showing in navigation .

```
let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
        button.titleLabel?.text = "dsfjksdf"
        button.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black;
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(GigDatesViewController.btnNext), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Comment: Check if you have navigationItem.

Comment: Where is the code that you posted in your question? Is it in `viewDidLoad` of a view controller class? Is the view controller embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: We are using xib's and I tried in viewDidLoad ,viewWillAppear both

Comment: Again, is your view controller in a navigation controller? Yes or no?

Comment: I write this code for navigation in app delegate

Comment: One last time. Please only answer "yes" or "no". Is your view controller inside a navigation controller?

Comment: This is in navigation controller

Answer (score -2):

I did try your code and I get barButton.title is nil or empty, so you can set image for button like:

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "image_name"), for: .normal)
```

Now you can see the image at the leftBarButtonItem.

If you want to use your custom text in the leftBarButtonItem you can use:

```
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "dsfjksdf", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(GigDatesViewController.btnNext))
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```